# Flask vs Web.py: Served files processed differently

Tags: python, flask

A .tar.bz2 file served from web.py is saved as .tar.bz2 from the browser. However when served by flask, the .bz2 extension is removed (but running file against the file still identifies it as a .bz2 file).

I have both frameworks running (web.py on python 2.7 and flask on python 3.7).
I manually put the same .tar.bz2 file in a directory and serve it from the web page.

```
Web.py:
=======
<form method="get" action="$fName">
  <div id="formsubmitbutton">
     <input type="submit" name="Retrieve File" value="Retrieve File" class="button3" />
  </div>
</form>

Flask:
======
<form method="get" action="{{ fName }}">
  <div id="formsubmitbutton">
     <input type="submit" name="Retrieve File" value="Retrieve File" class="button3" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I would expect both setups to return fName.tar.bz2. Chrome is returning the following and I have no clue why, but suspect it has something to do with my problem:

"Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-tar"

## UPDATE

Thanks for the tip. From Chrome though, that was the entire error message, minus the actual file name since there is customer information in there. Here is is edited error:

Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-tar: "http://foo.example.com:5000/static/1564445156.7369618/filename.tar.bz2?Retrieve+SSD=Retrieve+SSD".

Also, there is no traceback from web.py or Flask, because there is no error. it's just that when you click on retrieve file, web.py returns the full filename with .bz2 extenstion, and Flask returns the file without the .bz2 extension.

Comment: show code which you used

Comment: Thanks again for the comments. I will heed them in the future. I solved the problem by modifying app.route to “send_from_directory”. I’m new to flask. Learning as I go.

Comment: next time put code and full error message.

Answer (score 0):

The .bz2 files I am trying to serve are in the /static directory. By adding an app.route('/static') function, I was able to serve the file as a .bz2 without it being stripped of the .bz2 suffix:

```
@main.route('/static')
def sendfile():
  for key,val in request.values.items():
    filedir = '/home/admin/Flask/httsTools'+os.path.dirname(key)
    filename = os.path.basename(key)
  return send_from_directory(filedir, filename, as_attachment=True)
```

Whether or not this is the recommended way to do it I'm not sure, but it works.

Thank you for your help.